# Variable Javascript to PHP int

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, variables, int

I want to convert the Javascript variable to INT in php.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$res = '<script> var res = Math.max(screen.width,screen.height); document.write(res); </script>';

$int = (int)$res;
var_dump($int);
```

This code returns int(0) or value in String, I need the correct value in integer. 
For example 1920.

Comment: Because $res is considered as a string.

Comment: I need to parse this variable

Comment: Are you trying to assign the JavaScript variable value to PHP ?

Comment: I think you are trying to pass a JavaScript variable to PHP. You can't mix the two languages like this. You would need to send the JavaScript variable to PHP using an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `(int)` php tries to convert the given string to an integer, as if it start with a number, it'll use this number, for example:

`(int) "123cats"; // 123`

How you do not have any number in there php just got you a `0` as a result.
You cannot pass javascript variables to a php script in that way.
If you want to do it, you have to pass it in a `ajax` request or some sort of it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP script is executed in the server side, JS is interpreted at the client side.
In your case, you are trying to execute the `front-end` code in the `back-end`.
The assignment

```
$res = '<script> var res = Math.max(screen.width,screen.height); document.write(res); </script>';
```

is executed in the `server-side` and executed as a string. The `JS var` assignment will never happen in this case.
That's the reason it's returning `0`.

You can just execute the following code

```
$res = '100<script> var res = Math.max(screen.width,screen.height); document.write(res); </script>';
```

It will return `100`. Because int() will extract the `integer` value from the string.

Comment: Your code printed 100 + value, for example (1001920), but still STRING and I need INT type

Comment: Parsing int is easy in php-  inteval($res)

Comment: $res = '<script> var res = Math.max(screen.width,screen.height); document.write(res); </script>';
$a = intval($res);
var_dump($a);

RETURNS  int(0)

Comment: That should. Read my answer properly. That explains your question.

Comment: Ok, your code returns int(100) in type int, but I need the value of javascript, for example 1920.

Comment: Value of the JavaScript is determined in the `front-end`. Remember, first `Back-end` code is executed, then `front-end` .So, you will not be able to get the value of JavaScript in the PHP variable.

Comment: Okay, now I understand, of course.
You could tell me some method to do so?

I need to detect the screen resolution, and PHP condition by the value.
For example, if it is less than 1141, show X menu, else, show Y menu.
THANKS!!

Comment: What are X,Y menus ?

Comment: I need load one menu or another menu depends the resolution of the screen.

For example, X = Mobile Menu(width resolution 768) and Y = Desktop Menu (width resolution 1920). 
The menu code is programmed in html and php

Comment: Loading the menus can be done by HTML (`front-end`) itself. You don't have to do anything with the `back-end`. From PHP you can get the data, but how you render it is decided in the `front-end`.